# Equation of motion in a paraboloid

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, spring, constrained-dynamics

I am not a physicist I started reading a book about Lagrange and Hamilton equations, where is easier to solve physics exercises than using the usual Newtonian method. But maybe I have some concepts maybe not very clear.

I have an exercise;

a particle of mass $m$ moves without friction on a paraboloid, with a vertical axis, $$z=ax^2+by^2$$ An ideal spring of elastic constant $k$ acts on the particle.

(a).Determine the Lagrangian and the particle equations using x, y, as generalized coordinates.
**my question is: generalized coordinates refers to that I cannot transform the coordinates to cylindrical.**

well, this is my best try...

$$L= T- V$$

$$T =\frac{1}{2}m\left(\dot{x}^{2}+\dot{y}^{2}+\dot{z}^{2}\right)$$

$$V = -mgz - \frac{1}{2}k z^{2} $$

$$\dot{z}= 2ax\dot{x}+2ay\dot{y} $$

so
$$L =\frac{1}{2}m\left(\dot{x}^{2}+\dot{y}^{2}+ (2ax\dot{x}+2ay\dot{y}\right)^2) -mg(ax^2+by^2) - \frac{1}{2}k (ax^2+by^2)^2 $$
**This is correct?**

**How can I find the conserved quantity in these equations?**

Comment: the conserved quantity is the energy which is T+V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generalized coordinates refer to the fact that x and y are mapped onto the open curved surface of the paraboloid.

Your answer looks correct but I don't understand the spring in the question. Maybe you're correct in your assumption that the spring will only respond to changes in z. But what would make more sense to me is that it pulls the mass back towards a fixed point.

Eli is probably right about the conserved quantity.

Comment: thanks, you're right, the spring pulls the mass towards the origin of the system, 
that way, will the equations be equally correct?

Comment: Hey Chris, in that case wouldn't the force exerted by the spring be F = k * ( distance to the origin - spring equilibrium) ??

Comment: I think you are right, but I don't know the distance to the origin - spring equilibrium...so

Comment: I'm guessing that the spring equilibrium is a constant length which will disappear once you take the derivative of the lagrangian. However, the stored energy cannot simply be kz^2 but rather k*(distance to the origin) which is dependant on z, x, y not only z.